# Proper translation for nib sugar, coarse sugar, decorating sugar

Tags: translation, food

Supposing that one can find everything on Tfaobao, I tried it but I didn't find this specific type of decorating sugar for baking.

笔尖糖 or 粗糖 don't bring me proper results. I guess I am not translating it right.

[image: Example]

Comment: on the net find images for 装饰糖  decorating sugar 
(grains too large ?)

Comment: I tried 装饰糖 in Taobao, it returns tons of results. You can try it.

Comment: thank you all! your hint led me to the proper word: 珍珠糖. now I also get results!

Answer (score 2):

What a simple question.Nib sugar we called it 珍珠糖.Coarse sugar called 砂糖.And decorating sugar called 装饰用糖 or 烘焙装饰糖.

Comment: 红(黄）／白糖，brown/white sugar, 粉糖 pulverized sugar